# Dateadd and Datediff function in oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I want to use Oracle but DATEDIFF  and DATEADD function doesn't work in Oracle DB.

How to write below mentioned code in Oracle?

```
datediff('QUARTER', pr.StartDate, SYSDATE)

datediff('MONTH', pr.StartDate, SYSDATE)
```

Comment: Please check [FAQs on **Asking**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and make it  [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(**MCVE**)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do in this case is to use Oracle's `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` function.

Instead of:

```
datediff('QUARTER', pr.StartDate, SYSDATE)
```

you would use:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN(pr.startdate, SYSDATE) / 3
```

and instead of:

```
datediff('MONTH', pr.StartDate, SYSDATE)
```

you would use:

```
MONTHS_BETWEEN(pr.startdate, SYSDATE)
```

Keep in mind that `MONTHS_BETWEEN()` will return fractions of months, so use `TRUNC()` or `ROUND()` if you need an integer number.

Of course, if you need days instead of months, you can simply subtract one date from another, e.g., `SYSDATE - pr.startdate` or vice-versa.

If you need to add days to a date, you can simply to this:

```
pr.startdate + 1 -- where 1 is the number of days
```

And if you need to add or subtract months, use the `ADD_MONTHS()` function - unlike `INTERVAL`s this function is safe to use in leap years.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so for datediff('YEAR', pr.StartDate, SYSDATE) it will be MONTHS_BETWEEN(pr.startdate, SYSDATE) / 12

Comment: `MONTHS_BETWEEN(pr.startdate, SYSDATE)/12`

Comment: for datediff('DAY', pr.StartDate, SYSDATE)?

Comment: Just subtract one from the other as I mentioned in my answer: `SYSDATE - pr.startdate` or vice-versa. If you need an absolute value wrap it in `ABS()`: `ABS(SYSDATE - pr.startdate)`

Comment: I have a very complex conversion i guess. Can you provide me a oracle conversion for  "dateadd('DAY', -1, dateadd('MONTH', (FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(p.StartDate, SYSDATE) / p.Duration) + 1) * p.Duration, p.StartDate))" I have converted a bit but can you provide me conversion for reamining part?

Comment: @jay, as near as I can determine it's this: `ADD_MONTHS(p.StartDate, ( FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(p.StartDate, SYSDATE) / p.Duration) + 1) * p.Duration ) - 1`. But if you tell me more about what you're trying to do, specifically, I might be able to offer a simpler solution. And might I suggest asking another question, since your original one has already been answered?

Answer (score 0):

These do not have simple exact equivalents because of the semantics of `datediff()`.  It counts the number of "boundaries" between two date/times.

I believe these are semantically equivalent:

```
trunc(months_between(trunc(pr.StartDate, 'Q'), trunc(sysdate, 'Q')) / 3)
months_between(trunc(pr.StartDate, 'MONTH'), trunc(sysdate, 'MONTH'))
```

Because of the truncation to the first day of the quarter/month, these should not be returning fractions.

Comment: dateadd('DAY', -1, dateadd('MONTH', (FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(p.StartDate, SYSDATE) / p.Duration) + 1) * p.Duration, p.StartDate)) ..What would be exact conversion for this as i am halfway through

Comment: @jay . . . This question is already about *two* constructs (which is rather broad).  If you have *another* question, ask it as *another* question.